# Python logging Adapter Json

Tags: python, json, logging, adapter

I have some problem with my Custom Adapter:

Here is the code:

```
class MAdapter(logging.LoggerAdapter):
    def process(self, msg, kwargs):
        my_task_id = kwargs.pop('task_id', self.extra['task_id'])
        return '[%s]' % my_task_id, kwargs
```

It works fine, but I need id to be Json. Does it possible to make the adapter to Json?
I have tried to use python-json-logger, but I don't find a way to make it work with that. The task_id field have to be dynamic.
Here is the code for the python-json-logger:

```
class CustomJsonFormatter(jsonlogger.JsonFormatter):
    def add_fields(self, log_record, record, message_dict):
        super(CustomJsonFormatter, self).add_fields(log_record, record, message_dict)
        if not log_record.get('timestamp'):
            # this doesn't use record.created, so it is slightly off
            now = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
            log_record['timestamp'] = now
        if log_record.get('level'):
            log_record['level'] = log_record['level'].upper()
        else:
            log_record['level'] = record.levelname
        log_record['TASK_ID'] = "no_task_id"
def init_json_logger():
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
    formatter = CustomJsonFormatter('%(timestamp)s %(level)s %(name)s %(message)s')
    logHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(logHandler)
    adapter = NGUSAdapter(logger, {'task_id': NO_TASK_ID})
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```